# Median Time to Restore Services not showing in dashboard ( four key metrics)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I have been trying to implement four keys in gitlab. the Median Time to Restore Services data is not getting displayed . I have given 'incident' label after creating an issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup and config?

Comment: Did you create the issue with the **type: incident**?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the lack of API.

Only [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#project-level-time-to-restore-service-api) (March 2022) comes with:

> ### Project Level Time to restore service API
>
> In this release, we added API support for Time to Restore Service. This is the 3rd of the 4 [DORA Metrics](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/ci_cd_analytics.html#devops-research-and-assessment-dora-key-metrics). This data helps teams continuously improve in their stability metrics.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_9/ttr_api.png -- Project Level Time to restore service API]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/dora/metrics.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/299096).

---

And [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#enhancing-visibility-into-value-stream-with-dora-metrics) (June 2022) adds (in non-free GitLab):

> ### Enhancing visibility into Value Stream with DORA metrics
>
> With the addition of the four DORA metrics tiles to the Value Stream Analytics dashboard, you can now track team performance and value flow from ideation to customer delivery.
>
> Additionally, we added a new trend chart for the DORA Time to restore service metric to provide insights into software stability and reliability trends. This new chart shows information about how long it takes an organization to recover from a failure in production.
>
> This is the third DORA chart that’s available out of the box in GitLab. We plan to keep improving the visibility into DORA metrics and also add charts for the fourth metric: Change failure rate.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_1/vsa_dora_n_ttrs.png]

---

[GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#track-important-incident-timestamps-on-the-incident-timeline) (February 2023) adds another option/tool which can help with incident timing:

> ### Track important incident timestamps on the incident timeline
>
> Incident metrics are a set of standard, quantifiable measurements used to track the incident response process.
> Accurately tracking these metrics will help DevSecOps teams understand how they are performing and whether responses to unplanned outages are getting better or worse.
>
> With this release, you can specify optional incident tags to capture relevant incident timestamps. Added tags are displayed next to the timestamp.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_9/incident_tags.png -- Track important incident timestamps on the incident timeline]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/incident_management/incident_timeline_events.html#incident-tags) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8741).